# Can't export an OBJ

Tags: objects, export, import

I use blender a lot to make people profile pictures for all different types of game, but mainly popular ones like Roblox and such. I'm not an expert however and I stick to simple designs like my profile picture.

*Whenever I export an obj the bar on the top with the object name turns red, and I can't put in the object.***

[image]

Comment: Red colour of the bar means that the filename is already in use in the curent folder ie You have to rename the file or overwrite it, thats all (hit ENTER and save as usual). **Eventually You could press "+" on the Numpad to add the number after the name and make that way a new** (unused) **name.**

Comment: Hm. I tried that, but the thing is it happens with all of my files, and even the ones that I made like 3 weeks ago and worked then.

Comment: It would appear you clicked `Chris.mtl` which set the filename and the new export data can be found in `Chris.mtl.obj`